# Как добавить проверку на стороне сервера в форме?

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день. Написал форму рег-ции, сделал проверку введенных данных на стороне сервера на php (прповерка только после обновления страницы), но хочу сделать эту проверку на стороне сервера без обновления страницы. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю самым лучшим вариантом будет [AJAX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX)

В библиотеке **jQuery** есть [удобное решение](http://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Спасибо. А проверку на php могу так и оставить без изменений, просто добавить запрос на ajax, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Griin можно вынести обработчик формы в отдельный файл, к которому будут производиться обращения. Задача файла - дать ответ (вывести), например, "**ok**" если обработка корректна или "**error**", если возникла ошибка. JavaScript на текущей странице получит этот ответ и Вы уже можете отобразить это на экране. Рекомендую Вам погуглить несколько примеров, чтобы стало понятнее.

Comment: я вижу похожие темы тут же, гляну их, думаю, разберусь потихоньку. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В HTML5 есть богатые возможности для валидации(проверки) на стороне клиента без скриптов. Это очень удобно. Думаю вам будут полезны: [тип поля email](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email) , [аттрибут required](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/required) , валидация поля [аттрибутом pattern](http://htmlbook.ru/html/input/pattern) . Есть ещё много чего.

Есть конечно возможность использовать скрипты для валидации, но сейчас стараются это делать минимально, и юзать более красивые средства.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я как раз сейчас читал об этом, тоже довольно простая и удобная штука на стороне клиента